# Fraction of positive, negative & zero values of an array

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need to find fraction of positive, negative and zero values of an array. Here `int n` is the size of array. I've written the following code:

```
static void Fraction(int n, int[] a)
{
    double pos = 0, neg = 0, zero = 0;

    for(int i=0, j=n-1; i<j; i++, j--)
    {
        if(a[i] > 0)
            pos++;
        if(a[j] > 0)
            pos++;
        if(a[i] < 0)
            neg++;
        if(a[j] < 0)
            neg++;
        if(a[i] == 0)
            zero++;
        if(a[j] == 0)
            zero++;
    }

    if(n%2!=0)
    {
        int m = n/2;
        if(a[m] > 0) pos++;
        if(a[m] < 0) neg++;
        if(a[m] == 0) zero++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(pos/n);
    Console.WriteLine(neg/n);
    Console.WriteLine(zero/n);
}
```

Can we improve this code, specially multiple if conditions?

Note: I found same [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140290/calculate-fractions-of-positive-negative-and-zeros) on code review but my approach of iterating array is different.

Comment: You can save on the dynamic number of comparisons using the product of two numbers (while the are at least that many - barring overflow: if product below zero, tally one positive, one negative. If product zero, one zero and one of the sign of the sum; otherwise, signs are identical: two of the sign of the first. I tallying needs reduction, just don't count positive numbers: compute their number from `n`(total) - #zero - #negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you counting from both ends?  That leads to code duplication (since you have every condition twice), degraded performance (because you're accessing two different memory locations, rather than one sequentially, and it is harder for the compiler to optimize), and introduces a bug where you miss counting the middle element if `n` is odd.

Comment: Fixed the bug. I am counting from both ends to reduce iterations. If length of array is 500 this code only do 250 or less loops. Isn't it better than looping size of array when array length is large?

Comment: indexing into an array is not a loop.

Comment: +1 for iterating from start to end. Code will be much clearer, without duplications and messing with odd/even array's length. @SiD if you warninig about performance do some benchmarks for your solution and simple array iteration (you can even use `foreach`).

Comment: Guys, thanks.. I just learned "indexing into an array is not a loop"..

Answer (score -2):

I seriously doubt burning from both ends is faster
Use `else`
Why do you need n if you have the array?
Don't use double for count
Below should be faster than what you have

```
static void Fraction(int[] a)
{
    int pos = 0, neg = 0, zero = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] > 0)
        {
            pos++;
        }
        else if(a[i] < 0)
        {
            neg++;
        }
        else  
        {
            zero++;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(pos);
    Console.WriteLine(neg);
    Console.WriteLine(zero);
}
```

Comment: I am not using double to count I used to calculate fraction and `n` is coming from user input, so just used it instead of re-calculating it.

Comment: @SiD Uh, double pos = 0, neg = 0, zero = 0;  What if that n is wrong?  Calculate?

Comment: That's hackerrank puzzle. They are giving me 2 inputs, array and its length. I am sure in this situation `n` never be wrong because inputs are coming from test cases.

Comment: Whatever dude.  Assume what you want.  It cost no more to read Length over the cost of passing and reading integer.  Let it fail if the wrong value passed.  You cannot even recognize double.   You have sloppy code and discredit a proper answer.   Why do you come to code review if you don't intend to improve your code?

Comment: I tried your code and with `int pos = 0, neg = 0, zero = 0` it's failing. Please help me understand. I don't meant to offend you.

Comment: @SiD _That's hackerrank puzzle. They are giving me 2 inputs, array and its length._ You should have stated that in your question, now it doesn't count.